# Replacing characters by chaining str.replace methods produces wrong result

Tags: python, string, replace

I want to be able to replace certain characters. The desired replacement order should be
A -> U, T -> A, G -> C, C -> G.

But for some reason, C does not get replaced with G. 
I've linked the code that I have so far.

```
v = "ATGC"
DNA = [v]
MRNA = []
for s in DNA:
    MRNA.append(s.replace('A', 'U').replace('T', 'A').replace('C', 'G').replace('G', 'C'))
print(MRNA)
```

Comment: The order of replace is wrong. `s.replace('A', 'U').replace('T', 'A').replace('G', 'C').replace('C', 'G')`

Comment: I've tried that, but now the G does not get replace with C.

Comment: From 5' to 3' A translate into T, But A translates into U

Comment: You might be interested in https://biopython.org/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `MRNA.replace('C', 'G').replace('G', 'C')` will replace any `'C'` by a `'G'` which is immediately replaced back with a `'C'`.

Instead of multiple `str.replace` you should use a translation table with [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans) and [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate). Since this works in a single pass, it both avoids undoing a replacement and gets more efficient as the number of call to `str.replace` increases.

```
def dna_to_rna(s):
    trans_table = str.maketrans('ATCG', 'UAGC')
    return s.translate(trans_table)

print(dna_to_rna('ACGTAC')) # 'UGCAUG'
```

Comment: Single pass doesn't necessarily mean more efficient, since that single pass might be more complicated than each of the alternative several passes. Might even end up being slower overall.

Comment: @HeapOverflow It is asymptotically more efficient as the number of replace increase. If it is for four use of replace, I do not know, but in any case translate is the idiomatic way to do multiple character replacements in Python. I did reword my answer to make this clear.

Comment: Ok, I can agree with that :-). In the meantime I did some benchmarks, yours was about 4 times faster than mine (which uses five `replace`) on ASCII strings, but about 12 times *slower* than mine when I added a non-ASCII character (`'ö'`).

Comment: @HeapOverflow That is a very interesting result, thanks for sharing. I am sure we can find a SO question where this has been covered, I'll try to find one and link it here.

Comment: They're [special-casing](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/363fab83b8a0e6d924c7a7c577feec6a2812bb8c/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L9020) ascii => ascii translation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this is, each `replace` is changing the last `replace`'s output - meaning after you run `.replace('C', 'G')`, the string becomes `"UACC"`, and the next `replace` will replace all `C`'s into `G`'s, meaning you get `UAGG` instead of `UACG`. To fix this, you can use a `for` loop to loop though each character and use a `dictionary`:

```
def DNA_to_RNA(s):
    mask_table = {"A": "U", "T": "A", "C": "G", "G": "C"}
    result = []
    for char in s:
        result.append(mask_table[char])
    return ''.join(result)
```

Or, using list comprehension:

```
def DNA_to_RNA(s):
    mask_table = {"A": "U", "T": "A", "C": "G", "G": "C"}
    return ''.join([mask_table[char] for char in s])
```

Answer (score -1):

For the swap of `'G'` and `'C'`, you *could* use `'T'` as a buffer after you replaced all original `'T'` (so you know that at that point there aren't any `'T'` in the string and thus that's safe):

```
>>> 'ATGC'.replace('A', 'U').replace('T', 'A').replace('C', 'T').replace('G', 'C').replace('T', 'G')
'UACG'
```

Similar to the non-Python swap of two variables `c` and `g`:

```
t = c
c = g
g = t
```

instead of

```
c, g = g, c
```

Comment: at least use another letter as a buffer, less error-prone

Comment: @JulienD No, *more* error-prone, as any other letter might be in the string.

Comment: To my understanding, DNA sequence data often uses extra letters besides the ones corresponding to normal bases, to indicate that multiple different bases might be found in that position.

Comment: @JulienD I don't know DNA, plus as Karl pointed out there might be other letters in there anyway. Using `'T'` works for *any* given string.

Comment: I didn't downvote. This code does work, but the only issue is that it seems confusing. DNAs are only made up of 4 different Nitrogen bases - A, T, C, G. Using T as a buffer may seem confusing since it is a common base in the DNA. Therefore, using any other buffer letter than these 4 would be more ideal to avoid confusion.

Comment: @MT756 Well, if used in code, it could be mentioned in a comment. The question isn't tagged with `dna-sequence` or `bioinformatics` or any other tag like that and it also doesn't specify the alphabet. So I'm treating it as the general `python` / `replace` question it is presented as. In which case using any other character is dangerous. Though all that said, I think Olivier's answer is the proper way, and I would've upvoted it already if he didn't claim efficiency superiority with a wrong argument and with no proof...

Comment: @MT756 to be fair, not "any other": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleobase#Modified_nucleobases